# Setting a property for a CCLayer in a CCScene

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm developing a game with Xcode using Cocos2d 2.0fc0 and I've gotten hung up. I'd like to set a BOOL property when loading the CCLayer/CCScene Game class to define whether second player is local or a remote (Game Center) player. Problem is I'm not exactly sure how to do that under the circumstances. Here is what I've got so far:

```
@interface RemoteGame : CCLayer <GameCenterControllerDelegate> {
BOOL isRemote;
}

@property (assign, readwrite) BOOL isRemote;

+(CCScene *) sceneIsRemote: (BOOL) b;
```

-

```
@implementation RemoteGame

@synthesize isRemote;

+(CCScene *) sceneIsRemote: (BOOL) b {
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    RemoteGame *layer = [RemoteGame node];
    layer.isRemote = b;
    [scene addChild: layer];

    return scene;
}


-(id) init {
    if((self=[super init])) {
        if (isRemote) {
            [GameCenterController sharedController].delegate = self;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I'm loading the scene like so:

```
CCScene *trans = [CCTransitionFlipX transitionWithDuration:.75 scene:[RemoteGame sceneIsRemote: YES]];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:trans];
[self presentGCTurnViewController];
```

The scene loads fine, but the BOOL is not getting set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shown code `[RemoteGame init]` is called before `layer.isRemote = b;`.

`[RemoteGame node]` calls `init` method internally, and `init` checks `isRemote` flag (which is set to `NO` by default. When `init` completes you call `layer.isRemote = b;` but this does not set delegate. So you need to move `[GameCenterController sharedController].delegate = self;` into `setIsRemote` setter.

In general, you can easily check when `isRemote` flag is set by using "Watch variable" command in debugger.

Comment: Right on, that totally makes sense! I moved the delegate command as you outlined above and things are working as expected. Thanks!